# Cannot run an R script with Rscript: dyld: Library not loaded, etc

Tags: r

I am using R in Rstudio. 
I now want to run my scripts from the command line.
I created a simple script containing `print('hi')` in it. I then run it with `Rscript test.R`. I get the following error:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/cr517/anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libR.dylib requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 8.0.0
[1]    69999 abort      Rscript test.R

`which R` returns `/usr/local/bin/R`

I know what packages are in R but not libraries. What is 'dyld'?

I am on MacOS X.

Comment: In short, I would recommend not using anaconda. Use R from CRAN builds.

Comment: How? What is R doing in the anaconda folder? How can I ask it to use CRAN builds?

Comment: You tell me.  But `anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib` tells a story...

Comment: I've uninstalled R and removed all these anaconda R folders and reinstalled R from CRAN and Rscript works now!

Comment: Hooray -- I could make my comment answer for you to accept.

Comment: 'dyld' is a dynamic linked library on macOS